# Call to function in parent from .JS file from inside iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, iframe

I have JS file with uploader functionality.
This file called from an iframe window.
I need to show alerts to user according to his actions.

Here is what I've done and it's not works:

**From JS file:**

```
$('#btnUpload').on('click', function(){
    parent.CallToParent();
});
```

**And from UploaderWindow call to:**

```
function CallToParent()
{
   parent.ShowAlert();
}
```

**And on main window:**

```
function ShowAlert()
{
   alert('some alert');
}
```

Comment: Do you have another iframe in the iframe? or just one parent and one iframe?

Comment: JS file inside iframe that need to show alert

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it correct. Don't know if the `parent.CallToParent()` in the `click` event really refers to the function in the parent window. If it doesn't then you could do something like.

**From JS file:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnUpload').on('click', function() {
        callParent();
    })
});
```

**And from iframe:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/common/jq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="c.js"></script>
<script>
    function callParent() {
        parent.fn();
    }
</script>

<input id="btnUpload" type="button" />
```

**Main File**

```
<script>
    function fn() {
        console.log('Parent function called');
    }
</script>

<iframe src="b.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: See the code I posted above, it works for me.. I suspect that you are binding the event on the button before its rendered. did you try `console.log` in the event handler?

Comment: I can call from JS to it's parent function, but from this function it couldn't find the next parent. But when I call directly from iframe to it's parent it's work fine. What the difference?

Comment: Why are you calling `CallToParent` as if its a function defined in the parent window? it is in the same page where the JS file has been included. So it lies within the scope of the same window.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there's no interoperability of scripts between these two contexts.

If you have control of the `iframe` contents then you could implement a 'middle-man' service to pipe messages.

Comment: He said its a file uploader, how can he doesn't have control over its contents?